# Unable to find uibutton with image in uistackview inside uitableviewcell in xcuitestcase

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I am writing ui test cases for my view. I have some image buttons inside uistackview which itself is inside uitableviewcell of UITableview. I have also set accessibilityIdentifier for buttons but I am still not able to find the button. Following is my code in tableviewcell:

```
ctaButtonStackView.isAccessibilityElement = false
    bookFlightButton.isAccessibilityElement = true
    bookFlightButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "bookFlightButton"
    findMyTripButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "findMyTripButton"
    flightStatusButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "flightStatusButton"
```

Following is my design in storyboard:

[image]

When I try to debug my uitest cases I can see the button without any identifier whereas other fields have identifiers. Following is the response when I print all the buttons:

```
Output: {
  Button, {{2.0, 844.0}, {82.0, 48.0}}, label: 'Home', Selected
  Button, {{88.0, 844.0}, {81.0, 48.0}}, label: 'Book'
  Button, {{173.0, 844.0}, {82.0, 48.0}}, label: 'Trips'
  Button, {{259.0, 844.0}, {81.0, 48.0}}, label: 'Specials'
  Button, {{344.0, 844.0}, {82.0, 48.0}}, label: 'More'
  Button, {{164.0, 191.0}, {100.0, 100.0}}
  Button, {{306.7, 191.0}, {100.0, 100.0}}
  Button, {{21.3, 191.0}, {100.0, 100.0}}
  Button, {{8.0, 119.0}, {412.0, 32.0}}
  Button, {{980.0, 626.0}, {280.0, 35.0}}, label: 'Show fares '
  Button, {{1300.0, 626.0}, {280.0, 35.0}}, label: 'Show fares '
  Button, {{364.0, 323.0}, {49.0, 31.0}}, label: 'See all'
}
```

It shows frame of the buttons for which I am looking to write test cases but it doesn't have any label.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like button's `superview` is not an accessibility element.

```
ctaButtonStackView.isAccessibilityElement = false
```

Try setting this value to `true`.

Comment: Already tried it but it is still not working for me

Comment: You also need to make sure that button is visible and enabled/hittable during UI testing. By any chance is this button or it's superview hidden?

Comment: No I can see it during the test running

Comment: @Panks, were you able to fix this issue? If yes how did you solve this? Just seeing a similar issue with nested stackview button.